# Disable JIT Hotspot autovectorization

Tags: java, vectorization, jvm-hotspot, auto-vectorization

I want to disable the vectorization performed by the c2 JIT Hotspot compiler in Java such that to create a baseline for a JMH benchmark suite.

For now I pass the optional JVM argument `-XX:-UseSuperWord` to deactivate the Super word loop optimization.

Doing that all SIMD packed assembly instruction (e.g, vaddps) are not used, instead I can find SIMD scalar instruction (e.g, vaddss).

So as far as I know this should be enough, but I wonder if Hotspot has other vector optimization? If yes how it possible to disable them?